# jqGrid - Multiple grids on same page shows only one pager

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, javascript-framework

I am writing a page with multiple jqGrids. My code follows a JavaScript MVC pattern which is going to provide an API for my HTML elements (including jqGrids). So, in the end of the day, I can create grids by calling my API. Something like:

```
var grid1 = new grid();
grid1.init();
var grid2 = new grid();
grid2.init();
```

I have done it with other javascript components and it worked great. However, when I create multiple jqGrid instances on the same page there is only one jqPager on the page attached to the last grid. Does anybody have an idea why?

Here is my code (Note that this is a simplified version, in reality I keep it separated in different .js files and also follow many other design patterns):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.1.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
</head><body>

<!-- IMPORT JS -->  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.1.2/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.1.2/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>    

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    function grid() {
        //=== LOCA VARIABLES ===//
        var myGrid = $('<table>').attr( "id", "useraccount-search-datagrid");
        var myPager = $("<div>").attr("id", "useraccount-search-datagrid-pager");
        var localData1 = {
            "page" : 1,
            "totalRecords" : 5,
            "pageSize" : 3,
            "rows" : [
                { Name : "Name 1"},
                { Name : "Name 3"},
                { Name : "Name 2"}
            ]
        };

        function publicInit(){
            $("body").append(myGrid, myPager);
            myGrid.jqGrid({
                pager : myPager,
                data: localData1.rows,
                datatype : "local",
                colModel : [
                    { name : 'Name', index : 'Name', width : "500"}
                ],
                localReader: {
                    repeatitems: false
                },
                rowNum : 3,
                viewrecords : true,
                height : "auto",
                ignoreCase : true
            });
        }
        //=== REVEALING PATTERN===//
        return {
            init: publicInit
        }
    };

    var grid1 = new grid();
    grid1.init();

    $("body").append("<br><br>"); //Add some spacing to distinguish between both grids

    var grid2 = new grid();
    grid2.init();

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your code produce `<table>` and `<div>` elements with **the same** id attributes. So the second grid `var grid2 = new grid();` just add `<table>` and `<div>` elements which already exist on the page. It's a bug. All `id` attributes of all element on one HTML page must be unique. So the lines `myGrid = $('<table>').attr( "id", "useraccount-search-datagrid");` and `var myPager = $("<div>").attr("id", "useraccount-search-datagrid-pager");` must be changed.

If you need just to assign *some* unique ids you can use `$.jgrid.randId()` method used in jqGrid internally. The code could be

```js
var myGrid = $("<table>").attr("id", $.jgrid.randId());
var myPager = $("<div>").attr("id", $.jgrid.randId());
```

Moreover I strictly recommend you to use name conversion used in JavaScript. If you need to use `new` operator to create an object you should rename the function `grid` to `Grid`.

Comment: You are right. I did it and worked. I am going to use random ids for now and enhance this solution later. In my opinion, jqGrid should not consider any id in my case since I am passing the object instead any id ({pager : myPager}).

Comment: Write, name conversion is not an issue. I'm using namespaces which is not shown in my example

Comment: @YoriKusanagi: If you would use jqGrid option in the form `pager : myPager` then jqGrid will normalize it immediately to the form `pager : "#" + idOfPager` (see [the part](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L2410-L2417) of jqGrid code). jqGrid constructs the id of many internal elements of the grid based on id of pager of id of the grid. The one must assign some ids.

Comment: @YoriKusanagi: About the name conversion and style of writing the program: it it really strict recommended to use the style used in *the language in which you write* and not just repeat the style which you use in other computer languages. Is it good to use `var variableWhichHaveAlwaysOnlyIntererValue = true;`? If one would see the variable `variableWhichHaveAlwaysOnlyIntererValue` in the middle of the code one will misunderstand your code. Do you know at least one JavaScript function which not hold naming conversion which I mention? One uses `var d = new Date();` just because of the name.

Comment: thanks for your clarification. Yes, I realized it now. Well, there are a few things I personally do not like, such as need to have myGrid (<table>) and myPager (<div>) elements in the 'body' before creating myGrid.jqGrid({}). Well, anyways it is a great product I just need to adjust my framework to work smoothly with it :D
Thanks for you great help.

Comment: @YoriKusanagi: You are welcome! I recommend you to validate your JavaScript code in [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or in [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/). If you set some options in comments you will be able to find many potential problems in you code. The most well-known JavaScript libraries uses the tools.