# how to avoid duplicated dynamic id on partialViews elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, partial-views

I have a project where I Crete jquery tabs and load them whit partial views using Ajax (all done dynamically), in have some shared partial views like "selectUser", the problem is that some tabs will use this partial view at the same time, so i will be duplicated ids, then i said "no prob" ill use class and more specific selectors, but i can't get jqgrid to work using class selectors.

So im looking for a nice way to:
    -Create dynamics ids
or
    -make jqgrid work using classes

Answer (score 0):

[Add a prefix to each different item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898321/asp-mvc-3-razor-add-model-prefix-in-the-html-partialview-extension)

```
public static void RenderPartialWithPrefix(this HtmlHelper helper, string partialViewName, object model, string prefix)
        {
            helper.RenderPartial(partialViewName,
                                 model,
                                 new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = prefix } });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand you correctly. If you use jqGrid you need have `<table>` element on the grid with *some unique id attribute*. If you generate `<table>` element dynamically you can first generate unique id then create `<table>` element with the id attribute. The method `$.jgrid.randId()` can help you. The usage is very easy. You can find code examples in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16306237/315935).

Another problem exist because one *have to* assign unique `id` attribute to every row of the grid. If you fill the grid without specifying any `id` for the rows in the input data or if the native ids for the grids could have *common values* (the same rowids in different grids) you can have id duplicates in the data. You can solve the problem by usage of `idPrefix` option. If you specify *different* values of `idPrefix` option in all grids on the page (for example `idPrefix: "g1_"` for the first grid, `idPrefix: "g2_"` for the second one and so on) the rowids will be constructed from `id` and the `idPrefix`. So you will have unique rowids in the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.Partial("_Address", 
new ViewDataDictionary() 
{ 
  TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo() { HtmlFieldPrefix = "ShippingAddress" }
})
```

The variation of Partial() helper used above uses ViewDataDictionary parameter to specify TemplateInfo. The HtmlFieldPrefix property of the TemplateInfo must be set to the name as your choice.

Result:

```
<input id="ShippingAddress_Street" name="ShippingAddress.Street" type="text" value="" />
```